# python - replace value of unknown key in json

Tags: python, json

I'm pretty new to Python, so here is my question.

I am making an HTTP call to fetch some JSON data that was created with Javascript. This JSON may have some values like `"nan"`, `"inf"` or `"-inf"` as strings. The keys and the depth of those values are unknown. What I want to do on the Python side, is to find those values and replace them with the Python equivalent of `float("nan")` or `float("inf")`.

Changing anything on the Javascript side is out of the question, as I was told.

I use the following function to read the HTTP response and return the JSON equivalent

```
def http_response_to_json(response):
    response_str = ""
    CHUNK = 16 * 1024

    while True:
        try:
            chunk = response.read(CHUNK)
            if not chunk:
                break
            response_str += chunk
        except httplib.IncompleteRead, e:
            response_str += e.partial

    return json.loads(response_str)
```

I've read up on the `object_hook` parameter of `json.loads` but I'm not sure if and how I can use it.

P.S. I'm using Python 2 still

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the data with JSON.loads, you can use a recursive function to clean up the data. Here's an example of how you can do this.

```
def cleanup(dirty_data):
    if isinstance(dirty_data, dict):
        for key in dirty_data:
            value = dirty_data[key]
            dirty_data[key] = cleanup(value)
        return dirty_data
    elif isinstance(dirty_data, str):
        if dirty_data in ["nan", "inf", "-inf"]:
            return float(dirty_data)
    else:
        return dirty_data

test_object = {"test": 123, "a": {"b": "nan"}}

print(cleanup(test_object))
```

This will output: `{'a': {'b': nan}, 'test': 123}`

---

**EDIT:** Here's a version that works with Python 2.

```
def cleanup(dirty_data):
    if isinstance(dirty_data, dict):
        for key in dirty_data:
            value = dirty_data[key]
            dirty_data[key] = cleanup(value)
        return dirty_data
    elif isinstance(dirty_data, str) or isinstance(dirty_data, unicode):
        if dirty_data in ["nan", "inf", "-inf"]:
            return float(dirty_data)
    else:
        return dirty_data

test_object = {"test": 123, "a": {"b": "nan"}}

print(cleanup(test_object))
```

Comment: had to change `isinstance(dirty_data, str)` to `isinstance(dirty_data, basestring)` for it to work. any idea why?

Comment: When I check the the type with `type("test")` and `type(json.loads('{"a": "123"}')["a"])` they say it's a `str` so I have no idea why it would be different for you.

Comment: In Python 2, json.loads returns `unicode` instead of `str`. That might be the reason if you're still using Python 2.

Comment: yes, that's why! forgot to mention it. I'll edit my question to include it, and maybe you can edit yours so it'll be complete